# Mac OS to Windows 11 using NextJS

Tags: windows, next.js

I just switched from mac os to windows 11, and already downloaded node.js, npm and vscode on my laptop. But every time I create a new next.js project. I get the following error:

```
    PS D:\CODING\next-app-stack> npm run dev
    
    > next-app-stack@0.1.0 dev
    > next dev
    
       ▲ Next.js 14.0.3
       - Local:        http://localhost:3000
    
     ✓ Ready in 3.8s
     ○ Compiling / ...
     ✓ Compiled / in 3.2s (501 modules)
     ✓ Compiled in 268ms (235 modules)
    <w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
     ✓ Compiled /favicon.ico in 221ms (506 modules)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
 ✓ Compiled /not-found in 282ms (511 modules)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies <w> [
```

When I run the app, it does appear on my localhost but every time I make a change it does not appear in my browser. I already tried deleting node models and next folder. But the error keeps appearing.

I also already tried npm run build

Why does it happen? Im new to windows, in mac os i I didn't get that error.

- Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm cache clean --force`.
After clearing the cache, try running your Next.js project again.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work: " npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
PS D:\CODING\next-app-stack> npm run dev

> next-app-stack@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

   ▲ Next.js 14.0.3
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000

 ✓ Ready in 4.4s
 ○ Compiling / ...
 ✓ Compiled / in 3.7s (501 modules)
 ✓ Compiled in 214ms (235 modules)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies

Comment: Try deleting the `.next` folder and try running `npm run dev` again. I really can't reproduce the error so I'm not 100% sure it's going to work but you can give it a try.

Comment: I already tried that... many times.